# What semantic notions underlie 'joining together' and 'impose, enjoin'?

Tags: etymology

I quote [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=enjoin). To wit, how did

> *in-* "on" (from PIE root [*en](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*en) "in")
>    + *iungere* "to join together" (from nasalized form of PIE root [*yeug-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*yeug-) "to join")

compound to mean

> "impose (on), inflict; subject to; assign (to)"

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first few OED entries for *enjoin* tell the tale.

1. *trans*. To join together. *Obs*.
2. In early use: To impose (a penalty, task, duty, or obligation); said esp. of a spiritual director
   (*to enjoin penance*, etc.). Hence in mod. use: To prescribe authoritatively and with emphasis (an action, a course of conduct, state of feeling, etc.).
3. To prohibit, forbid (a thing); to prohibit (a person) from (a person or thing, or some action).
   Now only in Law: To prohibit or restrain by an injunction.

So the way it worked was, first it was just joining together, then it became joining a rule with a person, then it became specialized on the nature of the rule, limiting it to a negative rule -- *Don't Do `X`*. Prohibitions have always constituted a pretty prominent variety of rule, after all.
OK?

Comment: Thanks. What do trans. and obs. mean?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Dictionary abbreviations; _trans._ identifies the verb _enjoin_ as a ***transitive*** verb, and _Obs._ identifies the definition as ***Obsolete*** -- i.e, _enjoin_ is no longer used to mean this in modern English (but may have been, in old texts).